# Помогите найти плагин для PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, плагин

Есть ли такой плагин для PhpStorm, чтобы если я в Google Chrome открываю инструменты разработчика и там редактирую стили CSS, то при переходе в PhpStorm там уже были внесенные изменения или чтобы шторм говорил что в хроме что-то поменяли и стоит ли ему тоже это поменять.

Answer (score 1):

Такого плагина нет. Зато есть [Live Edit](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/09/live-edit-in-phpstorm/)

Comment: Edit Live у меня почему-то не работает. Все делал как описано на офсайте и расширение от JetBrains ставил в браузер. Не получается. Пользуюсь live reload.